# Creating an index on ARRAY<STRING(MAX)> in Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to create an index on the `AlbumTokens` column in my Google Cloud Spanner test database and I get a mysterious error referencing an index option that is not currently documented:

```
CREATE INDEX AlbumTokens 
ON Albums (
    AlbumTokens
)

>>> Index AlbumTokens references ARRAY AlbumTokens, but is not declared as DISTINCT_ARRAY_ELEMENT index.
```

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

I'm using the sample schema with an `ARRAY<STRING>` column added on:

```
CREATE TABLE Singers (
    SingerId INT64 NOT NULL,
    FirstName STRING(1024),
    LastName STRING(1024),
    SingerInfo BYTES(MAX),
) PRIMARY KEY (SingerId)

CREATE TABLE Albums (
    SingerId INT64 NOT NULL,
    AlbumId INT64 NOT NULL,
    AlbumTitle STRING(MAX),
    AlbumTokens ARRAY<STRING(MAX)>,
) PRIMARY KEY (SingerId, AlbumId),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Singers ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Did you find a solution or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an index using an [Array](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model) as a key:

> Disallowed types
>
> These cannot be of type ARRAY:
>
> A table's key columns.
>
> An index's key columns.

You can include the Array in the index via the [STORING](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#storing_clause) keyword to return the array without joining to the primary table, but you can't scan on i